# SQL CE dependencies on PocketPC

Tags: c#, mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I build a PPC mobile program that uses SQL CE and Framework 3.5 on VS2008. Which files do I need to run or install before I can run my program?

Comment: The PPC in Windows mobile 2005

Answer (score 1):

The device needs .NET Compact Framework installed. It is automatically installed when you deploy directly from Visual Studio; otherwise, it can be installed with the [.NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en).

As for SQL CE, installation CABs are located within your Visual Studio folder, typically
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SQL Server\Client\v2.0`